# How to do a foreach type query in mysql, comparing each row with several rows in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I need to check each entryForm row's name and check if this name occurs in a list of SiteContacts where the .siteid and entryForm.siteid match.  (There is no point checking an entryForm row where the sites don't match.) I need to be left with the entryForms not matching.

An entryForm has one siteContact, a siteContact can have many entryForms.

```
select * from siteContacts, entryForm 
where siteContacts.siteid=entryForm.siteid 
and entryForm.name not like concat('%',siteContacts.lastname, '%')
```

siteContacts is a table like this:

```
id  |   lastname     |  siteid  
===============================
7   |   Cooper       |   2
8   |   Hofstadter   |   2
9   |   Wolowitz     |   3
10  |   Koothrappali |   3
```

entryForms is a table like this:

```
id  |   name           |  siteid  
==================================
1   |   Sheldon Cooper |   2
2   |   L. Hofstadter  |   2
3   |   Penny          |   3
4   |   Wolowitz       |   3
5   |   Dr Hofstadter  |   2
```

The result should be Penny :

```
3   |   Penny          |   3
```

but it's not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` because what you are dealing here are records that have no match on the other tables.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    entryForms a
        LEFT JOIN siteContact b
            ON a.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',b.LastName,'%')
WHERE   b.LastName IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ae9/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ SITEID ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  3 ║ Penny ║      3 ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Comment: How did you '_type_' that table? Which character are those vertical lines?

Comment: Just rewrote the query for the actual database and passed it for manual checking a random sample, as there's about 1500 results.

Comment: Dear JW, how would you limit to where they are from the same site? Basically it's no point comparing the two names if the form and site do not match.  IE check Site A form with Site A contacts only?

Comment: It may be good if you open another question for this so many others can be able to help you `:)` anyway what do you mean by *limit to where they are from the same site*?

Comment: Not sure how to phrase the questions yet, I was also wondering if your answer already does it:  eg A siteid 3 entryForm should be compared with siteid 3 siteContacts, and the entryForm should be returned where entryForm.name is not someone in siteContacts.lastName, for site 3.

Answer (score 0):

This I think is also a join like JW's above but written another way:

```
select * from entryForms
where entryForms.name not in (
  select entryForms.name from siteContacts, entryForms 
  where siteContacts.siteid=entryForms.siteid 
  and entryForms.name like concat('%',siteContacts.lastname, '%')
)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ae9/16